# Lydia won’t follow me!

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I’ve seen that many other people have had a similar problem where Lydia will only sit in your bedroom in breezehome. However, unlike *some* people, I don’t want to kill her, I actually enjoy her company and want her to follow me. But when I talk to her it’s as if she is following me and even after I part ways with her it still acts like she’s following me. I’ve tried a bunch of things and read other forums but nothing works. (I play on Xbox one btw)